# url pattern matching string parameter with space

Tags: python, django

I had problem matching URL pattern with a regular expression in Django.
urlpattern:

`url(r'^search/(?P<title>[\w\s ]+)/$',views.specs, name='spec'),`

url I am trying to match:

`/search/%20Iphone7%20jet%20black/`

***the title is something like this " iPhone 7 jet black"
Thanks in advance.***

Comment: you need to make your URL like /search/Iphone7jetblack/. this is the best practice while developing large applications. don't use blank space in URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
urlpattern: url(r'^/search/(?P<title>[-\w+\d+]+)/$', views.specs, name='spec')
```

And get the `title` parameter in your view where you can strip '%' signs. But the better option is to do this in your search form when cleaning form field data.

UPDATE:
@safwan your view.py should also contain

`def specs(request, title):
    do some magic here`

Comment: `%20` is decoded to a space before it is matched against the regex. Also, `\d` is a subset of `\w`.

Comment: `iPhone 7` does not agree with you

Comment: I already replace space with '-' and assign the string to variable urlstrip. in the URL pattern, I replaced title with urlstrip but it still dont match

Comment: @SafwanAbdulRahman you can give this answer some points then :)